# Drawing strings with slick2d and TTF

Tags: string, lwjgl, slick2d

I've been experimenting with String printing in LWJGL using slickutils. Generally when browsing the web I found two approaches to this. First being bitmaps where you have an entire alphabet and print each letter as a Texture, the other being using `TrueTypeFont`s and the `truetypefont.drawString(20f,20f,"LWJGL String Test", Color.green)` method.
However, most of the literature I found was a few years old. What is the right way to do this at the current time?

At the moment I'm using the `TrueTypeFont` method, however my result confuses me.
[image]

```
//It doesn't matter which Font I try to load, I get the same green bar. 
//I think it has something to do with not finding the Fonts?
Font awtFont = new Font("Times New Roman", Font.BOLD, 24); 
TrueTypeFont font = new TrueTypeFont(awtFont, true);
font.drawString(20f, 20f, "LWJGL TEST STRING",Color.green);
```

I've also copied an example from the internet and get the same result(just a bar).
Tried googling but couldn't find any fixes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TrueTypeFont is deprecated. Use UnicodeFont instead.

**Check this:**

```
// Create a font with the size of 20, and not bold or italic.
Unicode font = new UnicodeFont("res/font.ttf", 20, false, false);

font.addAsciiGlyphs();
font.getEffects().add(new ColorEffect());
font.loadGlyphs();

g.setFont(font);
g.drawString("Shit example", 100, 100);
```

Comment: Hm, from more googling it seems I should be using `BitmapFont` though I can't find any tutorials on that. Do you happen to know anything about that?

Comment: Bitmap font is made from an image file with splitting up. This i what i know. Oh and Minecraft uses Bitmap fonts too. :)

Comment: Oh after some searching, I got it. In Slick2d this is called  AngelCodeFont. 
`Font font = new AngelCodeFont("res/demo.fnt","res/demo.tga");`
[More info](http://www.slick2d.org/wiki/index.php/AngelCodeFont)